# How to delete Files in Data Source Tab?

Tags: tableau-desktop

[Image attached, I cannot figure out how to delete the extra files highlighted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5HIY.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to remove the files in the data source Connection, instead go to data source in sheet and close the data source as below and add the data source again with the one file wanted. [image]